# Copy a file with a given name

Tags: java

In my program I pass a directory path, a file's name which is in that directory, and the second directory where I want to copy the file.
Here's the program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        copyFile("C:\\Users\\Kacper\\Desktop\\Folder 1", "\\Text.txt", "C:\\Users\\Kacper\\Desktop\\Folder 2");
    }

    static void copyFile(String directory, String fileName, String secondDirectory) throws IOException {


        File source = new File(directory + fileName);
        File dest = new File(secondDirectory);

        Files.copy(source.toPath(), dest.toPath());

    }
```

Here's the screen of those folders:
[image: Folders]
This program throws me the FileAlreadyExistsException: C:\Users\Kacper\Desktop\Folder 2 
Why is that? Thanks for help :)

Comment: As far as I can see from the Javadoc, both source and target should be pointing to files. Currently your target points on the directory you want it in. Try adding the filename to onto dest

Comment: As far as I can see, `C:\Users\Kacper\Desktop\Folder 2` already exists. Is that exactly your problem? have you tried different names? Or removing files/folders and check the result?

Answer (score 0):

Add a copy option to your method:

```
    Files.copy(source, dest, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```